# datetime.strptime unable to convert

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a list of dates (where each entry is a string) to a datetime object.

The dates are formatted like:
2018-09-10 24:11

The code I've been using is:

```
dateTime = []


def makeDateTime(date):
    for entry in date[1:]:
        dateTime.append(datetime.strptime(entry, "%Y-%m-%d %H%M"))
    return dateTime

dt = makeDateTime(date)
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-5ac073b0f75a> in <module>()
----> 1 dt = datetime.strptime(date[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H%M")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    563     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    564     format string."""
--> 565     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    566     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    567     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    363     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    364         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
--> 365                           data_string[found.end():])
    366 
    367     iso_year = year = None

ValueError: unconverted data remains: :14
```

Even when I attempt to convert one entry outside of the loop it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: There is no time 24:11, are you sure you have dates like this?

Comment: `2018-09-10 24:11` vs `%Y-%m-%d %H%M` - the format string is missing the colon.

Comment: @timgeb poor example on my part.

Comment: @ForceBru that was it thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your dates look like `'2018-09-10 00:11'`, the correct format-string is `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` with a `:` between hour and minute.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2018-09-10 00:11', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 10, 0, 11)
```

However, you will still not be able to parse `'2018-09-10 24:11'` with this format-string. The time 24:11 does not exist, it should be 00:11. I'm assuming that's just a typo on your part for now.

In case minutes and hours are swapped, you can use `'%Y-%m-%d %M:%H'` (but I'm guessing at this point.)